# Merge two arrays with deeply nested key with Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ramda.js

I've recently started using Ramda to work with responses from JSONAPI. I am a bit confused as to how I should be merging two objects by a deeply nested key.

For example:

Take these two sets of data,

```
const users = [
    {   id: 1, 
        attributes: {
            firstName: "Bob",
            lastName: "Lee"
        }, 
        relationships: {
            phone: {
                data: {
                    id: 2, 
                    type: "phone"
                }
            }
        },
        type: "users"
     },
    {   id: 2, 
        attributes: {
            firstName: "Kevin",
            lastName: "Smith"
        }, 
        relationships: {
            phone: {
                data: {
                    id: 5, 
                    type: "phone"
                }
            }
        },
        type: "users"
     },
];

const phones= [
    {   id: 2, 
        attributes: {
            phoneNumber: "123-345-6789"
        },
        type: "phones"
     },
    {   id: 5, 
        attributes: {
            phoneNumber: "987-654-4321"
        }, 
        type: "phones"
     },
];
```

What I want to create is a new array with the related phone added to the user array with a new key holding all related objects, like this:

```
const newUser = 
[
  { id: 1,
    attributes: {
      firstName: "Bob",
      lastName: "Lee"
    },
    relationships: {
      phone: {
        data: {
          id: 2,
          type: "phones"
        }
      }
    },
    included: {
      phoneNumber: "123-345-6789"
    }
  },
  { id: 2,
    attributes: {
      firstName: "Kevin",
      lastName: "Smith"
    },
    relationships: {
      phone: {
        data: {
          id: 5,
          type: "phones"
        }
      }
    },
    type: "users",
    included: {
      phoneNumber: "987-654-4321"
    }
  }
]
```

I've tried multiple methods like map, pick, and join but the objects just don't seem to want to merge the way I want them to. The following code puts both of the objects into the same array, but I can't seem to wrap my head around where to go next.

```
const data = R.pipe(
        R.juxt([
          R.pipe(R.path(['users'])),
          R.pipe(R.path(['phones']))
        ]),
      )
}),
```

Comment: Are your actual object arrays?  Your samples use `{}` for the outer brackets, but no keys.  Should they be `[]`?

Comment: Also in `type: phone`, is phone defined elsewhere, or should this just be a string?

Comment: Actually it is in fact an object.. but I can turn it into an array with R.values, right? Also phone should be a string, sorry! I will edit that

Comment: Well, your sample code doesn't have any keys...

Comment: I changed the sets of data to arrays

Comment: I will try to take a swing at this in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my first approach:

```js
const {map, path, find, propEq, assoc} = R

const addPhones = (phones, users) => map(user => {
  const phoneId = path(['relationships', 'phone', 'data', 'id'], user)
  const phone = find(propEq('id', phoneId), phones)
  return phone
    ? assoc('included', phone.attributes, user)
    : user
}, users)


const users = [{"attributes": {"firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Lee"}, "id": 1, "relationships": {"phone": {"data": {"id": 2, "type": "phone"}}}, "type": "users"}, {"attributes": {"firstName": "Kevin", "lastName": "Smith"}, "id": 2, "relationships": {"phone": {"data": {"id": 5, "type": "phone"}}}, "type": "users"}, {"attributes": {"firstName": "Nancy", "lastName": "Johnson"}, "id": 3, "relationships": {"phone": {"data": {"id": 6, "type": "phone"}}}, "type": "users"}]

const phones= [{"attributes": {"phoneNumber": "123-345-6789"}, "id": 2, "type": "phones"}, {"attributes": {"phoneNumber": "987-654-4321"}, "id": 5, "type": "phones"}, {"attributes": {"phoneNumber": "212-867-5309"}, "id": 7, "type": "phones"}]


console.log(addPhones(phones, users))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

This version deals appropriately with missing values in either list.  If there is a user with no matching phone, the user is returned as-is, with no `included` property.  And if there is a phone with no matching user, it is simply ignored.

This makes the assumption that you can include the entire `phone.attributes` object in your user.  If you need to include only the `phoneNumber`, it's only slightly more complex, replacing the obvious line with

```
    ? assocPath(['included', 'phoneNumber'], phone.attributes.phoneNumber, user)
```

Comment: thanks, i will look into this approach. is it possible to do all of this in one pipe?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all in one pipe".  If you mean a point-free version of it, then I'd say it would not be pretty.